# Dispatcher for Filter Mapping

Tags: java, jsp

I have an app written for Servlet Spec 2.4 with an old webserver designed for Servlet Spec 2.3. The web.xml file has the following syntax:

```
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>   
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>    
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
</filter-mapping>
```

How can I re-write this mapping to be servlet 2.3 compliant?

Answer (score 12):

You can just remove the `<dispatcher>` entries. The Servlet 2.3 filter by default dispatches on everything and that's just okay. Sitemesh even mentions at its own site that it's compatible with Servlet 2.3. Here's an extract from [their site](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/requirements.html):

> SiteMesh is a Servlet Filter and therefore requires a container that conforms to the **Servlet 2.3** specification.

Comment: I am not sure if in servlet 2.4 spec if you delete all the <dispathcer> tags, the filter executes allways or never.

Comment: @David: since 2.4 it executes by default on `REQUEST` only. For `INCLUDE` and `FORWARD` you have to specify the `<dispatcher>` yourself (in addition to `REQUEST`!).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the <dispatcher> tags.

Servlet 2.3 doesn't support dispatchers. If you don't do include, it doesn't make any difference. If you do have included servlet/JSP, you need to rename them so they are not filtered to get the exact behavior as 2.4.