# Both isAnonymous() and isAuthenticated() return false on error page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I have an error page which is displayed when a 404 response status is returned.
This page is generated thanks to a template mechanism (I use tiles); In this template, I have a header that contains something like that :

```
    <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
        blabla
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
        blibli
    </sec:authorize>
```

So, depending on if the user is authenticated, it displays blibli or blabla. This code works for all pages that use this template except for my 404 page! It displays nothing!

Any idea??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll bet that problem lies in how you define `filter-mapping` in `web.xml`. Most common configuration is:

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This maps filter to all URLs, but only when they accessed by `REQUEST` method. All other cases (like `INCLUDE`, `FORWARD` and `ERROR`) not catched by this filter. So to bind filter to `ERROR` requests, define it as

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

        <!-- apply Spring Security authentication to error-pages -->
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Try it. If not works then add `<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>` because Tiles, probably includes pages by this way.

See also:

- [Dispatcher for Filter Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968621/dispatcher-for-filter-mapping)
- [Specifying Filter Mappings](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html#bnagf)

Comment: Indeed! `<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>` works! I have learn something today :D

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for java configuration:

```
private void registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
  FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = servletContext.addFilter(
        BeanIds.SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN, new DelegatingFilterProxy());
  springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
  springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.ERROR), false, "/*");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this 404 page is out of your secured URLs then both isAnonymous() and isAuthenticated() will return false and nothing is rendered.