# Both isAnonymous() and isAuthenticated() are returning false

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I have a simple  page which is displays simple text depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

```
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    No, you failed!
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   yes, logged in. Well done!
</sec:authorize>
```

The above code displays nothing! which means both isAuthenticated() and isAnonymous() have returned false.

It is suggested here ([Both isAnonymous() and isAuthenticated() return false on error page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11999656/825957)) that I must use this configuration for my filter mapping:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <!-- apply Spring Security authentication to error-pages -->
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am not using XML, but my configuration is the same:

```
EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
```

Why else would this happen?

Edit:
This is my security context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            //Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS files.
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/static/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            //Configures form login
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=bad_credentials")
            //Configures the logout function
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            //Configures url based authorization
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    //Anyone can access the urls
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/auth/**",
                            "/login",
                            "/signin/**",
                            "/signup/**",
                            "/user/register/**"
                    ).permitAll()
                    //The rest of the our application is protected.
                    .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
            //Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain.
            .and()
                .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
}

/**
* Configures the authentication manager bean which processes authentication
* requests.
*/
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

/**
* This is used to hash the password of the user.
*/
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
}

/**
* This bean is used to load the user specific data when social sign in
* is used.
 */
@Bean
public SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService() {
    return new SimpleSocialUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

/**
* This bean is load the user specific data when form login is used.
*/
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new RepositoryUserDetailsService(userRepository);
 }
}
```

This the page controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

protected static final String VIEW_NAME_LOGIN_PAGE = "user/login";

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginPage() {
    LOGGER.debug("Rendering login page.");
    return VIEW_NAME_LOGIN_PAGE;
 }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `DispatcherType.ERROR` ?

Comment: Upon reading your comment I tried it, but it didn’t work. But it makes since that it doesn't  work with `DispatcherType.ERROR` as it is not an error page.

Comment: You might need to post your security configuration. Is the page you are looking at protected by the filter chain?

Comment: @DaveSyer thanks for your comment. I have added my security context. Am I wrong to think that the  "/*"  in `EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");` protected all of my pages.

Comment: On it's own that won't guarantee that anything is protected (I believe). You need `@EnableWebSecurity` and a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to complete the picture.

Comment: Where is your controller for the page that isn't rendering as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ApplicationContext must contain

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.social.user.detail.service"
})
```

In this package I have the my user class containing the following:

```
public interface UserService {

   public User registerNewUserAccount(RegistrationForm userAccountData) throws DuplicateEmailException;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not bypassing security for that URL like as follows:

```
<http pattern="/xyz.xx" security="none" />
```